# State change not reflecting on child component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have two child components updating the same state of a parent component. both the child component contains a loop and each element of the loop updates the state on click by event.

The parent Component:-

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState('')

const selectContact = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const {id} = e.currentTarget
    setSelected(id)
    console.log(id)
}


<ChannelList selected={selected} setSelected={selectContact}
          ....other props />

<FriendList selected={selected} setSelected={selectContact} ......other props />}
```

I have not included the whole component obviously.

The ChannelList component:-

```
{channels.map(channel =>
    <div key={channel.id}>
        <div id={channel.id}
             className={`channel-list ${selected === channel.id && 'selected-channel'}`}
             onClick={(e) => {
                  setSelected(e)
                  channelDetails(channel.id)
             }}

        // .....rest of my code
    <div>
}
```

The FriendList component:-

```
{friends.map(friend =>
     <div key={friend.id} id={friend.id}
          className={`friend-list-item ${selected === friend.id && 'selected-user'}`}
          onClick={(e) => setSelected(e)}>

     //.......the rest
     <div>
}
```

What I am trying to do is change the style according to the state. If I click different items within the same component the state updates and the CSS renders fine. But if I click anything on the other component, although the state updates the CSS styling stays on both the components.

[this is the what happens that i don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYAoF.png)

What i want is the styling should only render on one of the components.
I am using react hooks and Typescript.

In other words, if I click on a friend name, the selected channel should be unselected and vice versa.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, @Ashki80. Would it be possible to create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: I'll try. But imagine this. The parent component has got the state. When child B updates the state, although child B updates, child A does not (vice versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using any state management library like Mobx or Redux to observe changes? I think using one of them should solve your problem.

Comment: i used a mobx store and it solved the issue, but suppose the the project is small. I don't want to install a whole library just for a small issue as this. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

you have conflict with same ids on both components. there are some approaches to that I could suggest:

one, you could use a prefix to define your selected state:

```
const selectContact = (prefix: String) => (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const {id} = e.currentTarget
    setSelected(`${prefix}_${id}`)
}

<ChannelList selected={selected} setSelected={() => selectContact('channel')}
      ....other props />
<FriendList selected={selected} setSelected={() => selectContact('friend')} ......other props />
```

at channel and friend components you would verify also the prefix:

```
{channels.map(channel =>
    <div key={channel.id}>
        <div id={channel.id}
             className={`channel-list ${selected === `channel_${channel.id}` && 'selected-channel'}`}
             onClick={(e) => {
                  setSelected(e)
                  channelDetails(channel.id)
             }}

        // .....rest of my code
    <div>
}
```

other way, you could create another state to control which component is selected (which is pretty much the same as the prefix):

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState('')
const [componentName, setComponentName] = useState('')
const selectContact = (componentName: String) => (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const {id} = e.currentTarget
    setComponentName(componentName)
    setSelected(id)
}
 <ChannelList selected={selected} isComponentSelected={componentName === 'channel'} setSelected={() => selectContact('channel')}
      ....other props />
<FriendList selected={selected} isComponentSelected={componentName === 'friend'} setSelected={() => selectContact('friend')} ......other props />
```

at channel:

```
{channels.map(channel =>
    <div key={channel.id}>
        <div id={channel.id}
             className={`channel-list ${isComponentSelected && selected === channel.id && 'selected-channel'}`}
             onClick={(e) => {
                  setSelected(e)
                  channelDetails(channel.id)
             }}

        // .....rest of my code
    <div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the ids have rare chance of conflicting. They are guids produced from the backend. And i even consoled them. Passing the prefix is a good idea though.